# Having trouble with img2pdf and spaces in filenames

Tags: shell, find, quoting, wildcards, command-substitution

I am trying to convert a bunch of jpeg files to a pdf file.

When I type the filenames with the quotes all is fine:

```
$ img2pdf "./Page 001.jpg" "./Page 002.jpg" -o book.pdf
```

When I go for the wildcards, I get an error from img2pdf suggesting it got "./Page" instead of "./Page 001.jpg":

IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: '"./Page'

Here is the command I use:

```
$ img2pdf `find . -name "Page*.jpg" -printf "\"%p\" "` -o book.pdf
```

What might go wrong?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are all your `jpg`s in the same dir ? If so why not simply `img2pdf Page*.jpg -o book.pdf` ?

Comment: Indeed thank you very much, I must have been tired when I was looking for this convoluted solution with find...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are in bash, so ... bash will interpret some character as separators. it depends by content of $IFS (internal field separator) environment variable which have his default value to whitespace (space, tab and newline). So when it will find a space character inside your file name it will be interpreted as a separator and will split file name in one or more pieces (it depends on how many spaces, tabs or new lines will found).

Solution could be to change $IFS value to something that match your needs.
for example in you case only new line characters should be interpreted as a separator:

```
# first save current value
OLD_IFS=$IFS

# change value to something you need
IFS="\n"

# do what you need to do here
#############################

# restore default value of IFS
IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

for more details see this documentation
[IFS reference](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#IFSREF)

**EDIT:**

I just made some tests with img2pdf. I have 101 images named like

> name_0.png, name_1.png, name_2.png, ..., name_100.png

to put them in a test.pdf file I used this command
`img2pdf -o test.pdf name_{0..100}.png`

and there was no problems with this.
Then I made another test with files with spaces in names like:

> name 0.png, name 1.png, name 2.png, ..., name 100.png

and command is (space character is escaped by backslash):
`img2pdf -o test.pdf name\ {0..100}.png`

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks but now it seems it is getting too much instead of not enough: IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: '"./Page 001.jpg" "./Page 002.jpg" '

Comment: what do you expect that find command will be replaced with? can you provide and example?
for me it will print a single line containing all file names any of them quoted by double quotes. is you expectation something different?

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works with simple wildcards. I don't know what got me the find command in the mind, it was late yesterday...